# Type 'AngularFirestore' is not generic

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase

I'm getting the error

> Type 'AngularFirestore' is not generic.

```
import { AngularFireAuth } from 'angularfire2/auth';
import { AngularFirestore } from 'angularfire2/firestore';
import { Profile } from './../../models/profile';

export class LoginPage {

  profileCollection: AngularFirestore<Profile>

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are passing a type to `AngularFireStore` but it is not generic. Try just doing `profileCollection: AngularFirestore` rather than `profileCollection: AngularFirestore<Profile>`. Read more about generic types here: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html

Answer (score 1):

I think the type declaration for profile collection you want is `profileCollection: Observable<Profile[]>;`. Just make sure you are importing 'rxjs/Observable'.

Angular Firestore collections are returned as observables from the request.

AngularFirestore is really a service for making calls to the database but does not return data as it's own type.

Answer (score 0):

You're going to want to use different types when fetching this from Firestore. First off you want to have the constructor of `LoginPage` import `AngularFirestore` with a constructor method at the top of your class:

```
import { AngularFireAuth } from 'angularfire2/auth';
import { AngularFirestore } from 'angularfire2/firestore';
import { Profile } from './../../models/profile';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';

export class LoginPage {

  profileCollection: Observable<Profile[]>;

  constructor(
   private firestore: AngularFirestore
  ) {
   this.profileCollection = this.getProfiles();
  }

  getProfiles() {
   return this.firestore.collection(`collectionPath`).valueChanges();
  }

}
```

That is the direction you should be looking towards when fetching data, I am a bit confused as to your code above though. Is this all being contained in a Class Model? You should be making all of your Firestore requests in a Service and not handling this in a Model. The service will make this code easy to reuse around your application. Let me know if you need any more help with this.